# SQL Server group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to word my question so perhaps an example would be best.  I'm looking for a function or statement that would produce the following result from a single table.  For each name, return the row with largest id.

```
ID  NAME        ADDRESS

1   JOHN DOE    123 FAKE ST.
2   JOHN DOE    321 MAIN ST.
3   JOHN DOE    333 2ND AVE.
4   MARY JANE   222 1ST. AVE
5   MARY JANE   444 POPLAR ST.
6   SUZY JO     999 8TH AVE.

DESIRED RESULT

3   JOHN DOE    333 2ND AVE.
5   MARY JANE   444 POPLAR ST.
6   SUZY JO     999 8TH AVE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `row_number` window function. This allows you to establish a row number to the result set. Then you can define the grouping and ordering within the `over` clause, in this case you want to `partition by` (group) the `name` field and `order by` the `id` field descending.  Finally you filter those results `where rn = 1` which returns the max result for each grouping.

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes this does produce the desired results.  I'll have to do some homework on why it works, but I'm just glad it does work :)

Comment: @RyanWilson Updated with an explanation.

Comment: @djmst64 Updated with an explanation -- glad it helped.

Comment: @sgeddes Thank you for adding a more detailed explanation. +1 from me.